# hide a span without an id inside a specific ul

Tags: hide, html

I installed eshop plugin in wordpress and I've beed told I should hide the span to hide the title

this is the code

```
<ul class="eshop rand"><li class="eshop-product-127"><a class="itemref" href="http://localhost/sab/to-40-gr-mix/"><img ilo-full-src="http://localhost/sab/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/DSC_4171-150x150.jpg" src="http://localhost/sab/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/DSC_4171-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-150x150 wp-post-image" alt="DSC_4171" height="150" width="150"></a><a href="http://localhost/sab/to-40-gr-mix/"><span>to 40 GR MIX</span></a>
```

I want to hide the span inside that ul with that class (eshop rand)

remember I can't assign an id to that span

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use this css class

```
.eshop.rand span
{
    display: none;
}
```

or

```
.eshop-product-127 span
{
    display: none;
}
```